# How to get the wifi configuration file location in android

Tags: android, android-wifi

I'm developing an app that backup the wifi configuration from any android device (rooted)
so I want to know how to get the file location in the android device so can I deal with it.

I know there is a lot of location depending on your ROM or device

like `/data/wifi/bcm_supp.conf` or `/data/misc/wifi/wpa_supplicant.conf`

but I want to get it dynamically .

Comment: Care to explain, are YOU saving these settings to some place or have these settings already saved at some location and you just want to find them out? and please share what you have done so far, this will help answering.

Comment: These settings already saved at some location and I just want to find them out.

Comment: Check this out for a couple of locations, rest you have to find out with certain cases. http://alt236.blogspot.com/2011/04/android-wifi-password-locations.html

Comment: Thanks but also I still need a way to know all different location of the file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a `WifiConfiguration` instance like this:

```
String networkSSID = "test";
String networkPass = "pass";

WifiConfiguration conf = new WifiConfiguration();
conf.SSID = "\"" + networkSSID + "\"";   //
```

Then, for WEP network you need to do this:

```
conf.wepKeys[0] = "\"" + networkPass + "\""; 
conf.wepTxKeyIndex = 0;
conf.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.NONE);
conf.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.WEP40);
```

For WPA network you need to add passphrase like this:

```
conf.preSharedKey = "\""+ networkPass +"\"";
```

For Open network you need to do this:

```
 conf.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.NONE);
```

Then, you need to add it to Android Wi-Fi manager settings:

```
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE); 
wifiManager.add(conf);
```

And finally, you might need to enable it, so Android connects to it:

```
List<WifiConfiguration> list = wifiManager.getConfiguredNetworks();
for (WifiConfiguration i : list) {
    if (i.SSID != null && i.SSID.equals("\"" + networkSSID + "\"")) {
        wm.disconnect();
        wm.enableNetwork(i.networkId, true);
        wm.reconnect();
        break;
    }
}
```

In case of WEP, if your password is in hex, you do not need to surround it with quotation marks.

Comment: Thanks but not that what I'm seeking for, I just need a code dynamically return to me where is the wifi configuration file location